# Project Selection in Run Configurations on Eclipse is Empty

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm a newbie in Android Development. And I have this one tini-tiny problem which I'm not able to fix it. Every time I run configurations, and browse the Project name, the Project selection is empty and I cant click on any on it except the "Cancel" Button. Then I can't really launch my project. How does one fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Java Perspective choose the `Run` menu and go to `Run Configurations`

Select the item in the list titled "Android Application" and press the plus/add button.

On the next page, choose the `Browse` button and choose the Android App that you'd like to run.

[image: image description here]

[image]

Comment: but when I tried to click browse, the Project Selection box can't be clicked or is empty.. here's the link of my dialog box, since I'm new in stack overflow and I can't post images for now.. https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=188811517975530&set=a.121235811399768.1073741828.100005400491688&type=1&theater

Comment: You project may not be an Android project.  Right click in the `Package Explorer` window and choose "New" -> "Other", find "Android" and choose "Android Application".  Then, just copy your .java files to the new project.

Answer (score 11):

Right click on your package in the Package Explorer, click Properties, and see if you're using any libraries.  Make sure that the "Is Library" box is not ticked on your project.

Answer (score 6):

In my particular case I had a Maven Project Loaded into Eclipse Mars, and when I tried to run a specific main class, the project itself didn't appear in the Project List under:

> Configurations -> Java Application -> Project -> Browse...

What I did was just to convert the Project to have Facets... in the Project Properties:

> **Main Menu -> Project -> Properties -> Project Facets**

Once I did it, just selected Java and the version I needed and it started working.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found I hadn't put the project name in Project textbox, in the first tab.